# Desktop Environment Switcher

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, desktop-environments

I have installed the Xubuntu and Xfce desktop environments and then tried switching between Xubuntu, Xfce and Unity via the login screen. I have noticed that some elements (login screen, full disk encryption password entry screen, boot splash, icons for terminal, wastebasket, etc) of Xubuntu / Xfce stay around even when I select Unity in the login screen. Is there any way to ensure one DE doesnt mess with the other?

Comment: Can you please clarify "some elements"?

Comment: Brute force = install on separate partitions